# 9 Digito e Contagem de Linhas via Regex Notepad++

Tags: php, regex, notepad++

**1º Dúvida:**

Como converter uma lista telefônica que está no formato:

```
1188888888
1288888888
3188888888
1187877766
```

para:

```
11988888888
12988888888
31988888888
11987877766
```

via notepad++ expressão regular?

Ou talvez se possível em PHP, pois tenho que fazer um loop em vários arquivos. Caso seja possível fazer esse "batch" em notepad e alguém puder me explicar xD

Lembrando que o DDD pode mudar. Toda a lista são de telefones celulares, então não precisa de confirmação para saber se é ou não é. Apenas precisaria que o regex andasse as 2 primeiras casas e adicionasse o 9.

Tentei fazer peripécias no PHP Dom mas não deu muito certo, muito menos usando o fopen... Consegui até imprimir o resultado bacana, mas não consigo exportar o valor final para o csv de volta. Se for o caso, vou fazer isso via notepad++ mesmo. É mais trabalhoso, mas parece ser uma solução mais simples.

Se alguém souber de algum aplicativo ou forma mais fácil de fazer isso...

**2º Dúvida**
Depois de adicionado o 9 digito, preciso adicionar um ponto e vírgula e a contagem da linha, ficando mais ou menos assim:

```
11988888888;1
12988888888;2
31988888888;3
11987877766;4
```

E claro, a lista é imensa, então precisaria que fosse de uma forma bem convencional. Se tiver como fazer as 2 coisas ao mesmo tempo com apenas a aplicação de 1 regex, seria ainda mais bacana :D

PS: Agora que notei que a última linha de todos os arquivos está em branca. Ou seja, se são 5000 linhas no arquivo, 4999 tem números, a última não. Logo a contagem deve se partir apenas onde tem número, para não "quebrar" o formatação do arquivo.

Alguém conseguiria fazer isso?
Valeu :D

**MINHA "SOLUÇÃO" EM PHP** (não está funcional pois não salva o resultado, apenas apresenta na tela)

```
<?php
$row = 1;
$handle = fopen ("Lista (1).csv","r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count ($data);
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
    $datanew = substr_replace($data, "9", 2, 0);
        echo $datanew[$c]. ";$row <br />\n";
        $row++;
    }
}
fclose ($handle);
?>
```

Porém ele só imprime na tela. Não consegui fazer ele sobrescrever o arquivo.

Comment: Se conseguiu, crie uma resposta não coloque esse código na pergunta. xD é mais ou menos assim que eu estava fazendo com o php

Comment: Não consegui, pois não está totalmente funcional. Ele não salva o arquivo. Ele apenas mostra na tela =/

Comment: vc pode criar um arquivo novo com as modificações usando `fopen` com `w+`, para adicioanr o `;` e o número da linha segue a mesma logica do `substr_replace()`.

Comment: Poderia me mostrar como fazer isso? Sou novato em php, algumas coisas só aprendo vendo xD. Estou fazendo aulas no Cursoemvideo.com com o Gustavo Guanabara.

Comment: No csv, só tem um telefone por linha?

Comment: Exatamente, 1 linha por telefone. Precisa converter para 9º dígito e ainda colocar ponto e vírgula e a contagem da linha na frente.

Comment: Você precisa verificar mais algumas coisas, como os "casos especiais" e também os numeros nextel.

Comment: Não tem "casos especiais" nem números nextel. As listas são números básicos, todos possuem DDD no início seguido de 8 dígitos. E são todos celulares. Ou seja, não preciso que o script faça verificações, pode ser um script "burro" que coloca o 9 na terceira casa e no fim ponto e vírgula e a contagem da linha. Não tem problema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Notepad++/Column mode

Com o notepad++ pode resolver esse problema em três passos.

1 - Adicionar o 9, coloque o cursos no terceiro caracter da primeira linha e ative o mode coluna menu edit>column mode ou (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), na caixa de dialogo digite o `9` e de ok.

2 - Repita o passo 1, porém dessa vez deixe o cursor no final da linha, no lugar do `9` adicione um `;`.

3 - Acesse o mode coluna novamente deixe o cursor após o `;`, na caixa de dialogo marque o radio `number to insert` em `initial number` coloque `1` que será o número da primeira linha e deixe `increse by` em `1`, finalmente de ok.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### PHP

Com o php não muda muito a lógica como a string parece bem formatada, isso pode ser feito baseado no tamanho.

`substr_replace()` é responsavel por adicionar primeiramente o `9` na posição `2` da linha manipulada. Outra adição ocorre no caracter `12`(final da string) onde é adicionado o `;`, seguido do número da linha(`$linha_atual) e de um quebra de linha(`PHP_EOL`), tudo isso é concatenado em`$arquivo_novo`que é o conteúdo do no arquivo, ele é criado com`file_puts_contents()`.

```
<?php

    $csvs = glob('*.csv');

    foreach($csvs as $index => $nome){
        $linha_atual = 1;
        $arquivo_novo = "";

        $handle = fopen ($nome, 'r');
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $linha_modificada = substr_replace($data[0], '9', 2, 0);
            $arquivo_novo .= substr_replace($linha_modificada, ';'. $linha_atual 
                             .PHP_EOL , '12');    
            $linha_atual++;
        }
        fclose ($handle);
        file_put_contents('novo'. $index .'.csv', $arquivo_novo);
    }
```

Comment: Já coloco as imagens

Comment: Caramba, sensacional!
Saberia me dizer se consigo fazer um batch disso?

Comment: Automatizar? @diego, acho que da pra fazer com php, depois edito

Comment: Isso! Automatizar. Pois em cada arquivo possui muitas linhas de números e são vários arquivos em várias pastas. Se der para executar por pasta seria sensacional. Testei gravar um Macro dentro do próprio Notepad++ mas parece que ele não repete as coisas que são feitas pelo ALT+C (Modo Coluna). Se conseguir fazer tudo via PHP melhor ainda. Os arquivos estão nomeados da seguinte forma: Lista (1).csv Lista (2).csv Lista (3).csv..... Lembrando que não preciso imprimir na tela. Eu preciso é que salve no mesmo arquivo. Ou seja, abrir, editar e salvar. Preciso na real é do arquivo modificado.

Comment: Dê uma olhada na minha pergunta editada @rray . Coloquei minha breve "solução", porém ela não está funcional pois não sobrescreve o arquivo csv.

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou. Obrigado =D. Sabe me dizer se teria como fazer um "loop" no nome do arquivo para abrir o subsequente? As listas são numeradas com parênteses entre o número. Ficando:  Lista (1).csv e o número 1 muda conforme o número da lista.

Comment: @Diego da sim, pode usar esse código: `$arquivos = glob('*.csv');` vai precisar de um `foreach` antes do `while` na hora de abrir o arquivo não sera mais o nome fixa, sera o nome da variável no foreach. Não esqueça de reinicar `$linha_atual` e `$arquivo_novo` a cada novo arquivo.

Comment: Poderia editar o script? Tentei com 'for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++' e depois coloquei o nome do arquivo '"Lista (".$i.".csv"' mas não funcionou :( Foreach ainda não sei usar.

Comment: @Diego logo edite novamente.

Comment: Consegui via FOR, porém a cada novo arquivo criado ele copia o anterior. Então o arquivo seguinte fica ainda maior. Como seria isso em FOREACH?